# Can polymorpism be applied to composition in c++?

Tags: oop, polymorphism, composition

I was planning on making a **2d chessboard game** using **classes** and other **OOP techniques**. I know a little on **polymorphism** and was wondering if the technique used in **polymorphism** whereby I can delegate duties to the children class from the base class is applicable via **composition.**

[Edited]
A chessboard has players.I want to polymorphically call method functions move defined in both players without having to say player1.move(), player2.move()

Comment: could you provide an example? what does polymorphism via composition mean?

Comment: _"and was wondering if the technique used in polymorphism whereby I can delegate duties to the children class from the base class is applicable via composition."_ Isn't that exactly what the [_Composite Pattern_](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite) describes?

Comment: A chessboard has players, I want to polymorphically tell both players to move their pieces without having to say player1.move() and player2.move()

Comment: it would be terrible if two of the most commonly used techniques wouldn't work together. Please provide us some code. Any example is fine, but without "Yes" is the only answer

Comment: Absolutely. You can use `virtual` methods that call the derived/child class's method from a base class reference, the same way that it works in, say, Java. You don't need it to use the principle of composition to structure your data, but it's there for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Preface

Don't get lost in design patterns or design techniques. This question seems like an XY problem. Always take a step back and consider what you want to achieve.

#### Target

A single call to ask both players to move.

#### TL;DR

If there is no other context, I'd say just call them!

#### Explanation

In general:

- A chess board always have two players. ( unless you're designing a specialized rule )
- A chess flow is always operated in round robin ( first, then second, and then repeat ).

So what's wrong a chess flow controller to call two players to move in fixed order?

What would you gain from applying polymorphism to replace following code?

```
void begin_round(){
   player1.move();
   player2.move(); 
}
```

You'd save two line of type by calling a move... Hey wait! That's what `begin_round()` does!
Polymorphism approach does not save anything but increase complexity of the system which is a bad sign for system design.

Most of time, an as stupid as possible design is better than a complex approach, unless the design would save a lot of maintaining or developing resource. If a design saves nothing, then don't use it until it's a must.

#### Others

Composition is quite common in your case since a `game` is a composition for `a board and two players.`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be implemented, what is your example?